# To index a complex number in Python list

Tags: python

In my Python script line

```
a=function(i)
```

so a is a result list. In this list, there will be four values, a negative number, a positive number, and two complex numbers. Only the positive one is useful for me and I want to index it. I write this for index, but it doesn't work

```
a=function(i)
for b in a:
    if a>0 and type(a)==type(0.1):
        return a
```

so how can I tackle it. Thanks.

Comment: your function(i) ,what it returns... and what is b?

Comment: Why do you put `a` into if statement - it is a list. You need to check `b` as it is list item

Comment: Is it a positive `int` like `3`, or a positive `float` like `3.0`, or even a positive complex with no imaginary part like `3+0j`?

Comment: the positive number and negative number are all float, not int.

Answer (score 1):

I had to solve almost exactly this problem and wrote a function to find the positive root and raise a ValueError if there was none:

```
def find_positive_root(a):
    for b in a:
        if type(b) == complex or b<0:
            continue
        return b
    raise ValueError('No positive root in {}'.format(a))
```

The advantage of writing a dedicated function for this is that you can test it:

```
In [6]: find_positive_root([-4.3, 2.3j, 3, (-4+8j)])
Out[6]: 3

In [7]: find_positive_root([1., -4j, -2.3, 4j])
Out[7]: 1.0

In [8]: find_positive_root([-1., -4j, -2.3, 4j])
     ...: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-138-a4ed7675f551> in <module>()
----> 1 find_positive_root([-1., -4j, -2.3, 4j])

<ipython-input-132-9cd37f48e3bb> in find_positive_root(a)
      4             continue
      5         return b
----> 6     raise ValueError('No positive root in {}'.format(a))

ValueError: No positive root in [-1.0, (-0-4j), -2.3, 4j]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `return` outside of a function, which is not legal.

To get the positive integer from your list, assuming "positive" and "negative" numbers are of `float` type<sup>1</sup>:

```
a = function(i)

index = None
for index, v in enumerate(a):
    if type(v) == float and v >= 0:
        break

print(index)
print(a[index])
```

This will put the index of the first positive real number of the list into `index`.

**How it works**

Basically, this code iterates over the list, and checks the type of the elements. If an element is a real number, its positivity is checked. If it is positive, the value of its index is put into `index`, and the loop is stopped.

---

<sup>1: If you rather mean "a `complex` object whose imaginary part is zero", then replace `if type(v) == float and v >= 0` by `if v.imag == 0 and v.real >= 0`. However, in your code you wrote `type(a)==type(0.1)`, so I assume that `a` is expected to be a `float`.</sup>

Comment: it still doesn't work. I was told by Spyder: local variable 'index' is assigned to but never used.  so may I have your help again, thanks!

Comment: @KensZheng Of course, `index` is not used in the code I proposed to you. But it contains the value of the index you're looking for. To convince yourself, print `index` after the `for` loop, and print `a[index]` as well. I edited my answer so as to highlight this. Also, there was a mistake in my code, so I corrected it. Now it effectively puts the index into `index`.

Comment: Why are you testing `type(v) == int`? OP does not say anything about that number being integer.

Comment: @tobias_k Right, I don't know why I assumed it was an integer Oo Fixing it.

Comment: sorry for that. in the list a, the negative number and positive number are all float, not int.     I was told again:   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not NoneType.    So why is that again. Thanks sincerely!

Comment: and i is also a float.

Comment: @KensZheng The `i` was different, but you're right. I edited my code.

Comment: I really don't understand why it doesn't work again. I changed the code as your updated one. I pretty sure that the list a=[-0.0324, 0.023, 23-11*I, 23+11*I], but the result I get is always the 23+11*I, not matter I changed the code as  if type(v) == int and v >= 0   or  if type(v) == complex and v >= 0    .  Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @KensZheng If I use the exact code I gave you, and I replace `a = function(i)` by `a = [-0.0324, 0.023, complex(23,-11), complex(23,11)]`, the output is `1` and `0.023`.

Comment: One more thing, maybe useful.  When I enter the code: type(function(0)[1])    the result is "sympy.core.numbers.Float".   and enter the code:  type(function(0)[3])   the result is   "sympy.core.add.Add".

Comment: @KensZheng I could not have guessed this. Try and replace `type(v) == float` by `type(v) == sympy.core.numbers.Float`.

Comment: I have tried it, but is still does not work. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. Eventually I have tried it out. Below is my code:

```
a=function(i)
for v in a:
    if  type(v) is sy.add.Add:
        pass
    elif v > 0:
        return v
    else:
        pass
return v
```

Note: I solve the function(i) using sympy and the complex number in the resultlist is sympy.add.Add.